# Python remove tuple from a Two-dimensional list

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a list of tuples in my Two-dimensional List,

> [('J04550', 6.666666666666667), ('J08062', 23.333333333333336),
>   ('B12961', 23.333333333333336), ('J02917', 6.666666666666667),
>   ('TY36608', 6.666666666666667), ('J08062', 6.666666666666667),
>   ('J04542', 6.666666666666667), ('J02917', 23.333333333333336),
>   ('TY36003', 6.666666666666667)]

I need to remove the tuples which contains **'J04550'**.

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: [x for x in my_list if x[0] != "J04550"]

Comment: use python filter
for example 
new_list = filter(lambda x: x[0]!='J04550',x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is it :

```
new_list = [x for x in my_list if x[0] != "J04550"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [x for x in a if x[0] != 'J04550']
```

would remove all occurrences.